# Turn Off macOS Mojave Screenshot Preview Thumbnails with defaults write command

Tags: screen-capture, mojave

I'm reading [this article](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/turn-off-mojave-screenshot-preview-thumbnails/), it works.

But how can I turn off macOS Mojave screenshot preview thumbnails with `defaults write` command?

I just don't know the key value to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The domain is `com.apple.screencapture` and the key is `show-thumbnail`.
So:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture show-thumbnail -bool TRUE
```

and

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture show-thumbnail -bool FALSE
```

Comment: How do you know what keys `com.apple.screencapture` expects?

Comment: @EnricoBorba [This blog post](https://pawelgrzybek.com/change-macos-user-preferences-via-command-line/) does a nice job explaining.